# Java Code to validate a name field

Tags: java, regex

I have a name field and I have to validate it against a regex which is supposed to accept only alphabets and spaces. Can I get a proper running code for the same.

I basically need to check if the string matches the pattern.

So if I enter "rahul bose" it should return true but if i enter "rahul-bose" or "rahul bose 9" it should return false.

I tried something like this but it fails always

```
package pckg;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TextRegex {
    private String name;

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean checkError(String name){
        String regex = "[A-Za-z]";
        if(Pattern.matches(regex, name))
            return true;
        return false;

    }
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        TextRegex textRegex = new TextRegex();
        textRegex.setName("nayanava");
        System.out.println(textRegex.checkError(textRegex.getName()));
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `"[A-Za-z]+";`, otherwise it will only match a single letter. (Or `[A-Za-z]*`if you want the empy string to return true as well.)

Comment: `String regex = "^[A-Za-z\s]+$";`